# Accessing mailbox for actor initialised through pool in Celluloid

Tags: ruby, celluloid

I have 2 actors in my app. Service and PushSocket. I am using mailbox for communication between two actors Service and PushSocket.
It works well when I just create single instance on PushSocket and add message to it's mailbox.

```
**File: service.rb**

Celluloid::ZMQ.init

class Service
  include Celluloid::ZMQ
  attr_accessor :pushsocket

  def initialize
    initialize_pushsock_actor
    send_messages
  end

  def initialize_pushsock_actor
    @pushsocket = PushSocket.new
  end

  def send_messages
    10.times do
      puts 'sending data'
      @pushsocket.mailbox << 'test'
    end
  end
end

**File: push_socket.rb**

Celluloid::ZMQ.init
class PushSocket
  include Celluloid::ZMQ

  def initialize
    async.wait_for_my_messages
  end

  def wait_for_my_messages
    loop do
      message = receive { |msg| msg }
      puts "Got a Message: #{message.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

But when try same with pool it doesn't work as expected. I do not receive any message in push socket.

```
**File: service.rb**

Celluloid::ZMQ.init
class Service
  include Celluloid::ZMQ
  attr_accessor :pushsocket

  def initialize
    initialize_pushsock_actor
    send_messages
  end

  def initialize_pushsock_actor
    @pushsocket = PushSocket.pool(size: 10)
  end

  def send_messages
    10.times do
      puts 'sending data'
      @pushsocket.mailbox << 'test'
    end
  end
end


**File: push_socket.rb**

Celluloid::ZMQ.init
class PushSocket
  include Celluloid::ZMQ

  def initialize
    async.wait_for_my_messages
  end

  def wait_for_my_messages
    loop do
      message = receive { |msg| msg }
      puts "Got a Message: #{message.inspect}"
    end
  end
end
```

To get this working, I am using instance method of push socket which gives proper results. Not sure whats problem when I try to use mailbox with pool size defined.

Comment: Where do you make a connection or bind a socket?

Comment: Inside PushSocket actor, I connect to a socket in initialize method. I didn't put connection code here, But you can find real version of PushSocket here https://gist.github.com/pandurang90/29eeb61f587ff3e8c6a1

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: No, I don't get any errors..

Answer (score 1):

### You are directly interacting with the mailbox of an actor, which `Pool` implementations block direct access to.

> But you shouldn't be directly interacting with the mailbox anyway.

**Instead of this:**

```
@pushsocket.mailbox << "test string"
```

**Do this:**

```
@pushsocket.write("test string")
```

---

**NOTE:** You still might have a logic error in your implementation of pools. When you write to a socket actor, you have no idea what underlying socket you're writing to. That is fine, *if* you are implementing some sort of sequence-agnostic pipeline, where each `push` socket connects to a single `pull` socket, and you don't care which socket actor actually performs the write operation.

Comment: Ok this works for me. I was referring https://github.com/celluloid/celluloid/wiki/Protocol-Interaction . So just thought if I can use same with pool as well.